# Why is the axiom of countable choice constructively valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, constructive-mathematics

I am reading Andrej Bauer's [Five stages of accepting constructive mathematics](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2017-54-03/S0273-0979-2016-01556-4/). Theorem 1.3 proves that the axiom of choice implies excluded middle. Shortly afterwards Bauer implies that the axiom of *countable* choice *is* constructively valid. However I can't see why the same proof doesn't show that countable choice also implies excluded middle.

The proof of Theorem 1.3 goes as follows:

For an arbitrary proposition $P$ define $A = \{ x \in \{0,1\} | P \vee (x=0) \}$ and $B = \{ y \in \{0,1\} | P \vee (y=1) \}.$

Since each of $A$ and $B$ is inhabited (by 0 and 1 respectively), by choice there is a function $f \colon \{ A, B\} \rightarrow A \cup B$ such that $f(A) \in A$ and $f(B) \in B$. Since $A, B \subseteq \{0,1\}$, we have exhaustive cases:

- $f(A) = 1$. Then $1 = f(A) \in A$, so $P \vee (1=0) $ , which is equivalent to $P$.
- $f(B) = 0$. Then $0 = f(B) \in B$, so $P \vee (0=1) $ , which is equivalent to $P$.
- $f(A) = 0$ and $f(B) = 1$. Then we have $\neg P$, for if $P$ were true, then $A = B= \{0,1\}$ so $0 = f(A) = f(B) = 1$, which is absurd.

In each case we have decided either $P$ or $\neg P$, so choice implies excluded middle.

Why doesn't the same argument go through with countable choice (``every countable family of inhabited sets has a choice function'')? The set of sets we index over here, $\{A, B\}$, is *finite*. What's to stop us defining $A_0$ and $A_1$ to be $A$ and $B$ above and then setting, e.g., $A_2 = \{2\}$, $A_3 = \{3\} \ \dots $ and using the choice function given to us by countable choice to run the same argument again looking at the values $f(A_0)$ and $f(A_1)$?

Comment: Note that Bauer does not say that the axiom of countable choice is constructively **provable**, but rather that it is adopted [as an axiom] in some flavours of constructive mathematics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key point is that, as Bauer mentions, countable choice refers to the statement "every family of inhabited sets indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ has a choice function".  In other words, given a family $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that each $A_n$ is inhabited, there exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\bigcup A_n$ such that $f(n)\in A_n$ for each $n$.

Classically, you could deduce the axiom of choice for finite families from this statement by putting your finite family in bijection with the first $n$ natural numbers and then extending the family in some arbitrary way on the rest of the natural numbers.  Constructively, however, you can't do this, because there isn't necessarily a natural number $n$ such that your finite set has exactly $n$ elements!  Indeed, this is crucially exactly what is going on in the proof of excluded middle from choice: if you knew the set $\{A,B\}$ had a cardinality that was a natural number, that would decide $P$: $P$ is true if $\{A,B\}$ has $1$ element and $\neg P$ is true if it has $2$ elements.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand, but let me check: is it also true that the axiom of choice holds for families of size $n$ for *each* finite $n$ constructively, but the union of these axioms ($AC_1, AC_2, \dots$) also doesn't imply excluded middle by the argument above, since we don't know the cardinality of $\{A,B\}$?

Comment: That's correct, if by "finite $n$" you mean that $n$ is a natural number.  Note that constructively there can be finite cardinalities that are not natural numbers, such as the cardinality of a set like $\{A,B\}$.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. When constructive mathematicians talk about finite sets doe they mean in the sense of Dedekind then? Or that they are "not infinite" in some other sense?

Comment: In your second paragraph, it's not immediately clear why you need a bijection rather than just a surjection (in the case in point from $\{0, 1\}$ onto $\{A, B\}$). What goes wrong if you only have a surjection is that the choice function $f$ can choose different elements for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ even if $f(0) = f(1)$.

Comment: @h4yz: The usual definition of "finite" in a constructive setting is that there exists a surjection from a natural number.

Comment: So an axiom such as "every finite (in the constructive sense) collection of inhabited sets has a choice function" would imply excluded middle, but this doesn't follow from countable choice (nor base constructive ZF)?

Comment: (By the way I guess that "every collection of cardinality equal to a natural number of inhabited sets has a choice function" *is* true in base constructive ZF?)

Comment: @h4yz: That's right.  (I believe your parenthetical guess is also right, but I don't know this stuff well enough to say definitively.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, this has been super helpful.

Comment: You may find this [ncatlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+set) helpful, because once you leave the classical setting, subtle distinctions between different notions of finiteness creep in. (I have just been reminding myself of some of them $\ddot{\smile}$.)