# Why do most constructivists accept the axiom of countable choice?

Tags: philosophy, constructive-mathematics

One obvious reason is that it is useful. But is there a philosophical justification for it? This axiom does not seem of constructive flavour to me since there is no clear way to construct a choice function of a countable collection of inhabited sets in general.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3502198).

Comment: @J.G. That does not give any philosophical justification to accept countable choice, it simply states that it doesn't prove LEM.  I don't think it is of much relevant to this question.

Comment: @J.G.  that strikes me as a duplicate.  This specific question is too sparse on justifications, from the author, for making their conjecture.

Comment: @CarlaParla If you are looking for philosophical justification, perhaps post on [philosophy.se].  As stated, the question you have asked here is really too vague and unfocused.  It appears to me that it is a duplicate of the post J.G. suggests, but it also seems to rest on an unjustified assertion (i.e. that "most constructivists accept AoCC".  Do you have evidence for that claim?

Comment: The linked question only appears to address, "why doesn't countable choice imply excluded middle?" But there are other axioms that are often rejected as non-constructive that are weaker than excluded middle. So they don't seem like duplicates to me.

Comment: @DanDoel I am happy to defer to your expertise vis-a-vis whether or not this question is a duplicate.  However, that is not really the crux of my decision to close this question, which is related to the vagueness and lack of context.

Comment: Bruh how did this question get 3 downvotes

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is going to depend on the sort of underlying model/notion that leads one to care about constructive logic. Not all of them validate countable choice.

One that does (which I am most familiar with) is realizability, which is what you use when your interest in constructive mathematics is due to wanting the logic to have a fundamentally computable character. The reason that the axiom of choice fails in general in realizability is that propositions of the form:

$$∀ x : A. ∃ y : B. P(x, y)$$

are realized by procedures that, for each representation of an $A$ pick a representation of a $B$ and produce a witness that they satisfy $P$. However, in general there can be multiple representations of each $x : A$, and there is no obligation for the realizer to pick representations of *the same* $y : B$ for every representation of $x : A$. By contrast, a realizer for:

$$∃ f : B^A. ∀ x. P(x, f(x))$$

must give a procedure that *does* pick representatives of the same $y : B$ for every representative of $x : A$. This is because functions must respect equality, while $∀∃$ needn't. So, for instance, moving from the former to the latter cannot be done when $A$ is the real numbers $ℝ$. We can realize:

$$∀x : ℝ. ∃ n : ℕ. x < n$$

(implicitly embedding $ℕ$ back into $ℝ$) because for each representation of a real number, we can approximate the real enough to figure out *some* natural number that is bigger, but which natural we pick will depend on the details of the approximation (which is allowed for $∀∃$). But, we cannot realize:

$$∃f : ℕ^ℝ. ∀ x. x < f(x)$$

because there is no way to compute *the same* natural number for every representation of a given real number (every total, computable function from $ℝ$ to $ℕ$ is actually constant).

Now, the reason that countable choice works is that there is actually only one representation of each natural number. So, the procedure from:

$$∀ n : ℕ. ∃ y : B. P(n,y)$$

*already* satisfies the criteria for being a function. Or, if you want to complicate things, you could represent natural numbers as finite bit strings,<sup>1</sup> so that there are redundant elements, like $00100$ vs $100$. *But*, there is a computable function that calculates a *canonical* representation for any given representation. And that can be used to realize countable choice.

So, at least from a realizability/computability perspective, this is the meaning of axioms of choice. They are statements that we can canonicalize representations of some type. For natural numbers, we can, possibly trivially. For anything else that is countable, we can do it by mapping back and forth between the natural numbers. And for real numbers, finding a canonical representation is an uncomputable problem.

I wouldn't be surprised if other settings often fit into this framework. I.E. when (countable) choice holds, it's because the type is in some sense 'uniquely represented.' And when it doesn't, it isn't, and the operation of finding a 'canonical representation' violates the intrinsic character that the logic is supposed to have (computability, continuity, smoothness, etc.).

1: If you want to get fancy, you could probably represent natural numbers as appropriate terminating expressions in some programming language. Then there are many representations, but we can canonicalize them by doing the terminating reduction to a canonical value.